# Cannot connect to MobileFirst Server during initialization

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am testing developing a Hybrid application in MobileFirst Studio and want to connect to MobileFirst Server during the app init.  I updated main.js file under MF_Project/app/[appNanme]/common/js/main.js init method with the following:

```
WL.Client.connect({
  onSuccess: function() {
    WL.Logger.info("onSuccess: connection success");
  },
  onFailure: function(err) {
    WL.Logger.info("onFailure: Exception: " + err);
  }
});
```

I then build the app for Android environment (right click the appName the one under MF_Project and select "Build for Android environment"). Then I ran the app as Android Application in emulator, but the log comes back with error

```
01-25 16:04:29.364: E/NONE(2755): Invalid invocation of method WL.Client.connect; Invalid value 'undefined' (undefined), expected type 'function'.
01-25 16:04:29.368: E/NONE(2755): Invalid invocation of method WL.Client.connect; Invalid options attribute 'onSuccess'. Invalid invocation of method WL.Client.connect; Invalid value 'undefined' (undefined), expected type 'function'.
```

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Where did you put the connect method? add your full main.js; 2) where are you testing it? device? simulator/emulator? preview?

Comment: #1.  I updated the main.js file that is under: MF_project/apps/[appName]/common/js/main.js inside the wlCommonInit() function .. #2.  I am testing in emulator.

Comment: Did you make sure to build the application? How arey ou running the application in the emulator? Edit your question.

Comment: I updated my questions with more detail in it.

Comment: Upload your project to dropbox.

Comment: I uploaded to https://www.dropbox.com/s/e6fw61f2jk5utin/MF_Hybrid.zip?dl=0

Comment: @AndiSetiyadi can you access the MobileFirst console through your emulator's browser? i.e.: http://YOURMFSERVERIP:10080/worklightconsole/

Comment: @Yoel .. Yes I can access the /worklightconsole fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the supplied project in MFP 6.3 using a Nexus 5 device running Android 5.0.1.

The application successfully connected to the MFP Server.
In the log I saw the `SUCCESSFUL: [object object]` message.

`[object object]` because you did not `JSON.stringify` the result.
For example: `WL.Logger.info("SUCCESSFUL: " + JSON.stringify(response));`

I think something is wrong with your generated AVD - try to create a new one, in addition to testing in an actual device.

Comment: Idan .. thank you for your input.  I tried changing the AVD to Nexus 5 with 5.x (API 21) and it works .. a bit head scratching since I intentionally build the android app using API 19 which should work with the AVD 4.x, but apparently not.  As of now I can live with 5.x.